# Is there any way to create dynamic slugs with Gatsby using a template component / page?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, slug, strapi

I am quite new to Gatsby and I'm wondering if I can create custom routes (slugs) as templates. The use case would be:

1. Access `/articles/name-of-the-article` route
2. Serve component `Article.js` populated with the information retrieved from an API (i.e Strapi headless CMS) using the `name-of-the-article` slug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigations, I found out that there is a much easier way to do so by using [gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths/).
All you need to do is install it with `yarn` or `npm` and then in `gatsby-config.js` you'll add these:

```js
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-create-client-paths`,
      options: { prefixes: [`/articles/*`] },
},
```

This means that every request slug like this: `/articles/the-slug` will request the `articles.js` page and using `Link` that provided by Gatsby, you can pass props through `state` prop like this:

`<Link to="/articles/the-slug" state={{ slug: "the-slug", ...etc }}>Anchor Text</Link>`

In this way, `src/pages/articles.js` becomes the template page for slugs prefixed with `/articles`.

Comment: Is there a way to access the slug from the articles.js page?  For example, if someone enters `mywebsite.com/articles/some-article` in their address bar instead of clicking a `Link` component, will the articles.js page component have access to `some-article` somewhere in its props?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Gatsby has docs for this: [Creating pages from data programmatically](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/programmatically-create-pages-from-data/). You need to create page slugs: [Creating slugs for pages](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-slugs-for-pages/). You need to add [gatsby-source-strapi](https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi) to your `gatsby-config.js`.

I have little experience with Strapi so you need to do some research how you can handle slug creation with Strapi.

Example code:

```
gatsby-node.js

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  if (node.internal.type === "The Nodes as defined by Strapi") {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: "The base paths as defined by Strapi" });
    createNodeField({ node, name: "slug", value: slug });
  }
};

exports.createPages = async function({ actions, graphql }) {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
{
  allStrapiArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
  `)
  data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(edge => {
    const slug = edge.node.fields.slug
    actions.createPage({
      path: slug,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/article-template.js`),
      context: { slug: slug },
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: It's pretty easy to handle slugs with Strapi, also I would like to manage this without GraphQL as I'm doing everything with REST. Do you think it's possible?